# zsh post command function/hook

Tags: shell, zsh

Is there an equivalent of zsh's precmd for performing a function after a command has completed?

I'm looking for a way to send myself a notification for any process that takes over 60 seconds. Zsh has a great ability to print a summary of the resources used for each command if the command takes longer than the value set in REPORTTIME seconds. From what I can tell, the only available option is to print the format in TIMEFMT.

(More specifically, I'm looking to send myself a notification with https://pushover.net/ if any process running in a detached tmux session takes over 60 seconds to complete.)

Comment: Why was this closed? It seems useful and makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: I agree, this is a good question and should not have been closed.

Comment: Seems like [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580675/zsh-preexec-command-modification) may answer it!

Comment: I would like this question to be re-opened please.

Comment: Have you tried `notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`preexec`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-preexec_005ffunctions) to start counting time since execution and then [`precmd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-precmd_005ffunctions) which runs *after* command execution finishes and *before* prompt is drawn to evaluate whether you want or not notification (and send it).

Comment: Is what you wrote about `precmd` really correct? I can't find any information about any hook being triggered _after_ command execution.

Comment: @simeg There is no hook *after* specific execution but you can use `precmd` which is first thing that runs after finishing the _previous_ command (even before printing out prompt). So yes, I believe it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
notify() {
  emulate -L zsh  # Reset shell options inside this function.

  # Fetch the last command with elapsed time from history:
  local -a stats=( "${=$(fc -Dl -1)}" )
  # = splits the string into an array of words.
  # The elapsed time is the second word in the array.

  # Convert the elapsed minutes (and potentially hours) to seconds:
  local -a time=( "${(s.:.)stats[2]}" )
  local -i seconds=0 mult=1
  while (( $#time[@] )); do
    (( seconds += mult * time[-1] ))
    (( mult *= 60 ))
    shift -p time
  done

  (( seconds >= 60 )) &&
      print -r -- "'$stats[3,-1]' took $time seconds"
  # Replace the `print` statement above with your notification call.

  return 0  # Always return 'true' to avoid any hiccups.
}

# Call the function above before each prompt:
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd notify
```